# Tor Browser in Tiny core linux Virtual Machine

Tags: linux

I have installed tor-browser in tiny core linux VM. It is installed but the browser is not opening. According to the site, it say's to simply download and run the start-tor-browser executable file. But it isn't working.Can anyone help me with the installation steps?

Comment: You're likely missing a set of standard linux libraries and software. Run it from the command line with the --verbose flag and add the output to your question, e.g. `./Broswer/start-tor-browser --verbose`