# How to run and build tor browser using source code at Tinycore linux

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, tor-install

I want to run and build tor browser using source code of tor-browser  at Tinycore Linux . How can i do it manually so that if i'll make some changes in tor-browser source code that changes should be reflect  when i will test tor-browser at Tinycore Linux. I searched at google  but most of the answer are too old when i followed those answer that did not work.

As given tor browser instructions for run and build using source code for linux  at this website
https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en
i followed those instruction at TinyCore Linux but those instructions are not launching tor browser.

I checked this link http://tinycorelinux.net/4.x/x86/tcz/src/tor/ 
but it is not giving clear solution.

My question are how to run and build tor browser source code at TinyCore Linux?
How will i check that whatever changes I integrated that will reflect in tor browser?

I am running Tinycore at VirtualBox.
I am newbie in tor browser and tinycore linux
Any idea will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, if you just wish to run Tor Browser you'd be best going back to your [old question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14240/tor-browser-in-tiny-core-linux-virtual-machine) and providing the requested information. Not that building Tor Browser from source will likely not resolve the issue of it not launching which is, as mentioned on the previous question, likely to do with missing linux libraries and utilities.

Comment: First things Sir  this not my question https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14240/tor-browser-in-tiny-core-linux-virtual-machine

BTW I checked as you said " missing linux libraries and utilities".but There is no utility and library missing. When I executed in terminal ./start-tor-browser.desktop. It is showing that 
"Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach' ..." but i am not getting ant sign of neither connecting tor network nor launch of tor browser.

Comment: For chromium i used ninja command to run and build at windows. same type of solution i am looking for tor browser if possible. if there is any other way then please let me know SIr @canonizing ironize

Comment: Well you're not interested in running Tor Browser, just building it so it doesn't matter that it won't run in Tiny Core Linux anyway and like the other user, who totally isn't you, you didn't try the suggested command.

Comment: Actually SIr I want to make some changes in tor browser source code for my own  regarding my college project. that's why i need to know how to build and run tor browser source code at tinycore linux.

Comment: Then it's likely going to be a lot easier to make changes to whichever individual component and replace the file in the official Tor Browser with your modified one than go through the full build process for every component.

Comment: @canonizing ironize Sir Suppose that i want to block history in tor browser, if i will change at repository of tor browser source code they will not allow me to do this. that's why i need my own so that i can make change in tor browser source code and can check. but unfortunately i don't know how to run entire source code after changing and how to check whatever changes i made that is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

As to Tiny Core Linux, I can't give specific instruction.

The Tor Project Wiki provides a guide on [how to build Tor Browser](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking#WaystoBuildTorBrowser).

The Tor Browser build process uses a system called Gitian for creating reproducible builds. To follow this method, since you don't have a pre-existing Ubuntu 14.04 installation or virtual machine, you'd be following the [vagrant](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/tree/vagrant/README.md) build process. Note that it requires use of virtualization which likely won't play well with your already virtualized environment.

In that case you may instead have to manually build the [patched Firefox](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/), [Tor](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/), [Tor Button](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git/) and [Tor Launcher](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-launcher.git/) then manually follow the steps that the [Tor Browser builder](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git) process automates to create a coherent Tor Browser package. Each of these will have it's own required libraries and build tools, that may not be available in your distro and may need to be manually obtained, built and installed.

Comment: I followed this link https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux

but these instructions are not launching tor-browser

Comment: So do you want to build it or run it? Because to find out why it can't run you need to try out my suggestion on the other question [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14240/tor-browser-in-tiny-core-linux-virtual-machine), which definitely isn't yours. Run the `start-tor-browser` bash script, located in the `Browser` folder inside the `tor-browser...` folder with the `--verbose` flag from the command line and report the results.

Comment: I want to integrate some functionality in tor browser source code of linux at tinycore linux (i can choose another light weight linux distribution if it is not possible for tinycore). after integrating functionality i want to check whatever changes I have done it is working or not. For example if i integrate chromium source code then i run in terminal "ninja -C out/default chrome" after that i double click on new build of chromium i check whatever changes I have done it is working or not. Same kind of things i am looking for tor browser in linux light weight distribution. if it is possible.

Comment: @canonzing ironize Sir i did tor-browser/Browser/ 
 ./start-tor-browser  I run this script still i am not getting tor browser . in instructions they said that  "This will launch Tor Launcher and once that connects to Tor, it will launch Firefox"  I have run several times above script i have not got Tor browser.

Comment: Yes if you could add the output of the command, as requested, we can see why it's not starting.

Comment: when i run the command in terminal "./start-tor-browser.desktop" I got output as "Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...", but it is not launching tor browser

Comment: That's not the command I asked you to run: `./Browser/start-tor-browser --verbose`

Comment: When i executed ./Browser/start-tor-browser --verbose then i got error "./firefox: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Comment: Are you running this on ARM or something? What architecture is your processor and operating system, check by running `uname -mpi`?

Comment: I am running 4.2.9-tinycore linux at Virtual Box. Processor- i686

Comment: And did you download the 32bit Tor Browser for Linux?

Comment: No i am using 64 bit tor browser for linux

Comment: i686 is 32 bit, so don't expect 64bit executables to work...try the 32bit version.